# Verify only 1 of the columns selected has a value before using coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am performing a migration and want to combine 5 tables into 1. There is a "master" table that holds the primary key for the 4 sub tables.

I want to verify only 1 of these sub tables have a value so when I perform the migration I can use coalesce without worrying about dataloss.

How can I query for a master that has more than 1 sub table populated?

Query:

```
SELECT 
    rh.RevisionHardwareID, --master
    rhd.RevisionHardwareID, 
    rhi.RevisionHardwareID, 
    rhz.RevisionHardwareID, 
    rhs.RevisionHardwareID
FROM RevisionHardware rh
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_Desktop rhd ON rhd.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_iSeries rhi ON rhi.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_zSeries rhz ON rhz.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_Server rhs ON rhs.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
-- where/having count of sub tables that are populated > 1
```

Sample:

```
RevisionHardwareID  RevisionHardwareID  RevisionHardwareID  RevisionHardwareID  RevisionHardwareID
2   NULL    NULL    2   NULL
3   NULL    3   NULL    NULL
4   NULL    4   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    5   NULL    NULL
6   NULL    NULL    6   NULL
```

The first column is the "master" and will always have a value, but I want to make sure only 1 of the 4 other tables has a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just sum the non null columns in a where clause.

```
SELECT 
    rh.RevisionHardwareID,
    rhd.RevisionHardwareID, 
    rhi.RevisionHardwareID, 
    rhz.RevisionHardwareID, 
    rhs.RevisionHardwareID
FROM RevisionHardware rh
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_Desktop rhd ON rhd.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_iSeries rhi ON rhi.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_zSeries rhz ON rhz.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
LEFT JOIN RevisionHardware_Server rhs ON rhs.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID
WHERE (
    (CASE WHEN rhd.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN rhi.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN rhz.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
    (CASE WHEN rhs.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use the `ON` clauses:

```
FROM RevisionHardware rh LEFT JOIN
     RevisionHardware_Desktop rhd
     ON rhd.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID LEFT JOIN
     RevisionHardware_iSeries rhi
     ON rhi.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID AND
        rhd.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL LEFT JOIN 
     RevisionHardware_zSeries rhz
     ON rhz.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID AND
        rhd.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL AND
        rhi.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     RevisionHardware_Server rhs
     ON rhs.RevisionHardwareID = rh.RevisionHardwareID AND
        rhd.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL AND
        rhi.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL AND
        rhz.RevisionHardwareID IS NULL
```